# Why does text shadow not work in Firefox on Unicode thought bubble ?

Tags: css, unicode, colors

Take this JsFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/5vo1erzu/1/

```
.tsh {
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 0 #00f;
-moz-text-shadow: 0 0 0 #00f;
-webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 0 #00f;
}

<div class="tsh">
xxxx
</div>
```

In Chrome, it displays all text, including the Unicode thought bubble, in blue.

In Firefox, it displays the text in blue, but the thought bubble has its original gray color.

Is there any way I can make this work in Firefox?

Comment: In order to make an emoji have the default text color, put a U+FE0E after it, like this: `xx&#xFE0E;xx` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/f02y1mou/). See also https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-12.0/emoji-variants.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly.